# Apply erosion to only a portion of an image

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to opencv and I couldn't find any solution for this problem of mine.

I wonder if it is possible to apply erosion/dilation only to a specific portion of an image and let the rest of the image remain as it is originally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get a submatrix of the area you want to apply erode/dilate to and apply the operation in-place:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = cv2.imread('image_to_process.jpg')

roi = im[:100, :100, :]
# define your_kernel as needed
roi[:] = cv2.dilate(roi, your_kernel) # the [:] is important
```

Note that I use `roi[:]` to have the result of `dilate` overwrite the content of `roi` instead of allocating a new matrix, so that the change actually reflects on `im` too.